# Does swapping $i \to -i$ in $f(x)$ always give $\overline{f(x)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am a physics student. Often we wish to find the complex conjugate of a function , for example

$$ f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}, f(x)=e^{ix},$$

To do this, we just replace all $i \to -i$. In the special case $f(x)=a(x)+b(x)i$ it is very clear that this is equivalent to conjugation. And for a particular function, like the one above, it is also easy to prove, so that is not my question. But is there a way to see that for *arbitrary* $f(x)$ or even $f(z)$, making the replacement $i \to -i$ always gives the complex conjugate?

Most valuable to me would be a "proof sketch" wherein I understand the reasoning, but maybe not every epsilon.

Comment: the replacement is not well-defined, where is the $i$ in $f(x):=\sqrt x$? or in $f(x):=\ln x$ for $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and $\ln{\cdot}$ expanded in some way on $\Bbb C$ when $x<0$? In these cases you would need to write the functions in some _canonical form_ where the $i$ appear. This doesn't seems feasible for an arbitrary functions.

Comment: @Masacroso Interesting. So since it does not work for these functions, it seems one might just have to really prove it one function at a time, or look at a restricted class of functions. It seems something should be provable though, since I've seen this replacement done on a large variety of functions and successfully give the conjugate.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work for $f(z)= iz$  where changing $i$ t0 $-i$ results in $-iz$ which is not the conjugate of $iz$

Another counter example is  $f(z)=e^{iz}$ where changing $i$ to $-i$ results in $e^{-iz}$ which is not the conjugate of $e^{iz}$

Comment: Thanks for the useful example. The remainder of the question is then just for functions of a real variable $f(x)$ which map in general to complex numbers.

Comment: In case of $f(x) = u(x)+iv(x)$, changing $i$ to $-i$ results in $u(x)-iv(x)$ which is the conjugate of f(x).

Comment: Yes, but essentially I was wondering why it works with a large class of more complicated examples, like $f(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + i sin(x)}{i(x+2i)(x-3i)}$

Comment: That comes from properties of conjugation which goes through addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Comment: Coming back to this question: it seems that the issue with the counterexamples you chose is that we didn't also conjugate $z$. So are there examples where properly conjugating all $i$, including the one implicitly hidden in $z$, does not result in $f(z)$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you mean $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}$, then, yes (at least for most well-behaved functions).

To start off, define $h(z)$ (where $z\in\mathbb C$) as being $=\bar z$ (for all $z$).

Now, suppose $u$ and $v$ are any two complex numbers with $u=a+bi$ and $v=c+di$.

Then:

$h(u+v)=h((a+bi)+(c+di))=h(a+c+(b+d)i)=a+c-(b+d)i=(a-bi)+(c-di)=h(a+bi)+h(c+di)=h(u)+h(v)$

And:

$h(uv)=h((a+bi)(c+di))=h(ac+adi+bci+bdi^2)=h(ac-bd+(ad+bc)i)=\\ ac-bd-(ad+bc)i=ac-bd-adi-bci=a(c-di)-b(d+ci)=a(c-di)-bi(c-di)=(a-bi)(c-di)=h(a+bi)h(c+di)=h(u)h(v)$

So we have, for any $u,v \in\mathbb C$: $\quad h(u+v)=h(u)+h(v)\quad$ *&* $\quad h(uv)=h(u)h(v)$

i.e. $\overline{u+v}=\bar u +\bar v\quad$ *&* $\quad\overline{uv}=\bar u\bar v$

So, suppose we have some polynomial $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...+a_nz^n$ where $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ are all real (so that $\overline {a_i}=a_i$ for all i).

Based on what we have shown,

$p(\bar z)=a_0+a_1\bar z+a_2\bar z^2+...+a_n\bar z^n=a_0+a_1\bar z+a_2\overline {z^2}+...+a_n\overline {z^n}=\overline {a_0}+\overline {a_1z}+\overline {a_2z^2}+...+\overline{a_nz^n}=\overline {a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...+a_nz^n}=\overline {p(z)}$

Now, no part of this argument excluded $f$ from having an 'infinite' degree, so to speak. So you could apply this to any function with a Taylor Series expansion (at least, over the domain where the series was valid).

**Edit**: $f$ restricted to $\mathbb R$ must map back to $\mathbb R$ so that the coefficients of its Taylor series are real

Comment: It is not exactly the same question I was asking, but a related one and certainly helped my understanding, thank you. At least if $f(x)$ can be written as $f(iy)$, then if $f$ can be written as a convergent series this works.

Comment: The question I was asking includes functions like $f(z) = iz$ where of course $\bar{f(z)} \neq f(\bar{z})$. Can we always get $\bar{f(z)}$ by conjugating every $i$, including the ones which are in $z$ and others which appear explicitly in $f$?

Comment: @doublefelix See my edit - essentially, the claim that $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}$ relies on the assumption that the coefficients of its Laurent series are real (so that the coefficients are unaffected by conjugation). This is guaranteed iff the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb R$ also maps into $\mathbb R$. The example function you have given does not satisfy this requirement (because e.g. $f(1)=i(1)=i$ is not real).

Comment: Right, I did understand that, and I greatly appreciate the help. The remaining question is: are there examples where properly conjugating all $i$, including the one implicitly hidden in $z$, does not result in $\bar{f(z)}$? The proof you gave works when the coefficients of the Laurent series are real, but I was curious about all functions $f(z)$ which can be expressed in closed form or as an infinite series. Because in physics, one usually just conjugates everything and assumes we get $\bar{f(z)}$ without second thought. I was curious whether there is legitimacy to that.

Comment: @doublefelix As I said before, there is legitimacy to that if the function $f$ you are working with maps $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ and has a Laurent series about $0$ that is valid everywhere. If these are the functions you work with in physics normally, then everything works out. Beyond that, it is hard for me to say.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the help :)